# Design of fully differential OTA circuits

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, differential, ota

This is the equivalent model of an ideal single-ended [OTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transconductance_amplifier):

[image]

This is the equivalent model of an ideal fully differential OTA:

[image]

Is there a rule for getting a certain circuit with a fully differential OTA starting from that of a single-ended OTA?

For instance, I have to realize this circuit with a fully differential architecture:

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: You are not looking for the implementation of the OTA, but for your last circuit (single-ended) in a differential version, correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the last circuit

Answer (score 0):

Use two single-ended amps.  Switch the inputs on one of them.